# ReflectionException in CommanderTrait.php line 59: Class App\FollowUserCommand does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I Was following Laracasts video for creating follow option but when I'm clicking on Follow button on members page it is showing the above error. This is my **followcontroller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Laracasts\Commander\CommanderTrait;
use App\FollowUserCommand; 
use Sentinel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class FollowsController extends Controller
{
use CommanderTrait;
/**
 * Follow a User
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $input = array_add(Input::all(), 'user_id', Sentinel::getuser()->id);
    $this->execute(FollowUserCommand::class, $input);
    return Redirect::back();
}


/**
 * Unfollow a User
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

This is my **FollowUserCommand**

```
<?php namespace App\User;

class FollowUserCommand {

public $user_id;
public $userIdToFollow;

function __construct($user_id, $userIdToFollow)
{
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
    $this->userIdToFollow = $userIdToFollow;
}
}
```

**FollowUserCommandHandler**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Laracasts\Commander\CommandHandler;

class FollowUserCommandHandler implements CommandHandler {

protected $userRepo;

function __construct(UserRepository $userRepo)
{
    $this->userRepo = $userRepo;
}




public function handle($command)
{
    $user = $this->userRepo->findById($command->user_id);

    $this->userRepo->follow($command->userIdToFollow, $user);

    return $user;
}

}
```

**UserRepository**

```
class UserRepository {

public function save(User $user) 
{
    return $user->save();
}

public function getPaginated($howMany = 4)
{
    return User::orderBy('first_name', 'asc')->paginate($howMany);
}

public function findByUsername($username)
{
    return User::with(['feeds' => function($query)
    {
        $query->latest();
    }

    ])->whereUsername($username)->first();
}

public function findById($id) 
{
    return User::findOrFail($id);
}

public function follow($userIdToFollow, User $user)
{
    return $user->follows()->attach($userIdToFollow);
}
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php namespace App;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class User extends EloquentUser {


/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes to be fillable from the model.
 *
 * A dirty hack to allow fields to be fillable by calling empty fillable array
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [];
protected $guarded = ['id'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

/**
* To allow soft deletes
*/
use SoftDeletes;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];   

    // This function allows us to get a list of users following us
public function follows()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'follows', 'follower_id', 'followed_id')->withTimestamps();
}

// Get all users we are following
public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'followers', 'user_id', 'follow_id')->withTimestamps();
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it is showing error even after "use App\FollowUserCommand;" has been declared in namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your namespace when declaring the *FollowUserCommand* class is wrong, it should be:

```
<?php namespace App;

class FollowUserCommand {...
```

And right now you have `<?php namespace App\User;`.

Comment: Thanks for helping can you tell me the how to get the feeds of the user whom you are following. Right now I'm able to get the id of the user whom you are following but struggling to get the feeds of the struggling user.